# First blog post is live

Tags: discussion, blog

Granted, this machine isn't as old as a lot of those that we discuss on the site, but it's older than I remember it being! Anyone have any feedback or care to share a story?

https://retrocomputingblog.wordpress.com/2016/08/17/i-accidentally-bought-a-pentium-machine/